# How do can I read a file from a website when it returns 'The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.'?

Tags: php, xml, file-get-contents

I want to read an xml file from this web page http://www.marketwire.com/rss/mwAS.xml and when I run this piece of code:

```
<?php
  $json  = file_get_contents('http://www.marketwire.com/rss/mwAS.xml');
  $xml = json_decode($json, TRUE);
  print_r($json);
  print_r($xml);
?>
```

I get this result:
"
    
     
      Request Rejected
     
     
      The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator. 
      Your support ID is: 4827530227059987189
     
    
"

What can I do for the website not to reject my request?

Note: I replaced the URL by google.com and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite probably the url is restricted by some scheme, maybe by domain or an ip address white list. Check the error code you get back from your file_get_contents call.

Comment: My IP was considered a malicious IP and marketwire was rejecting it due to that.; slthough that page I was trying to access was public. They were using brightcloud and I submitted a request to remove my IP off the 'high risk' list on brightcloud. They placed me on the safe list and the access worked.